# Understanding JSX element declaration syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have seen two different ways of declaring an element in JSX.

The first one looks as follows.

```
const element = (
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

But I have also seen following declaration for an element.

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    ...
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Both these elements can be passed to ReactDOM.render() as their first argument.

But what exactly is the difference between these two syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is evaluated immediately.  The second one is evaluated when its parent is rendered.

It's the difference between

```js
let y = 1,
  x = y;

y = 2;

console.log(x); // prints 1
```

and

```js
let y = 1,
  x = () => y;

y = 2;

console.log(x()); // prints 2
```

When you're designing reusable components, use the second syntax.  When you're returning or including a component in another component's rendering, use the first one.

Comment: What does () => () syntax mean here? It looks like an arrow function () => {} but it has parentheses at the end not curly braces.

Comment: Technically the outer parentheses are pointless.  The only time you do need them is when you start your element on the line after your return statement, as JavaScript doesn't require terminating your lines with `;`.  When an arrow function doesn't have curly-brackets, it treats it as a one-line return statement.  If it does have curly-brackets, it treats it like a regular function and requires a `return` statement if desirable.